# Deleting SSH keys terminal

Tags: macos, github, ssh, terminal

How would I delete `github_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa.pub` SSH certificates from my mac computer using mac terminal?

Comment: To clarify - are you referring to deleting the keys from Github, or your local computer?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Depending on where they are located:

```
rm github_rsa.pub
```

and

```
rm id_rsa.pub
```

If they are in the default location then you can do

```
rm ~/.ssh/github_rsa.pub
```

and

```
rm ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

However this is likely answered already elsewhere.